# what is the wrong with my Dividing Sequences code

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to code this problem:

> This problem is about sequences of positive integers a1,a2,...,aN. A
> subsequence of a sequence is anything obtained by dropping some of the
> elements. For example, 3,7,11,3 is a subsequence of
> 6,3,11,5,7,4,3,11,5,3 , but 3,3,7 is not a subsequence of
> 6,3,11,5,7,4,3,11,5,3 .
>
> Given a sequence of integers your aim is to find the length of the longest fully dividing subsequence of this sequence.
>
> A fully dividing sequence is a sequence a1,a2,...,aN where ai divides
> aj whenever i < j. For example, 3, 15, 60, 720 is a fully dividing
> sequence.

My code is:

```
n=input()
ar=[]

temp=0
for i in range (0,n):
    temp=input()
    ar.append(temp)

def best(i):
    if i==0:
        return (1)
    else:
        ans =1
        for j in range (0,i):
            if (ar[j]%ar[i]==0):

                ans=max(ans,(best(j)+1))
         return (ans)
an=[]
for i in range (0,n):
   temp=best(i)
   an.append(temp)

print max(an)
```

the input was

```
9
2 
3 
7 
8 
14 
39 
145 
76 
320
```

and I should get 3 (because of 2, 8, 320) as output but I am getting 1

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what a "fully dividing sequence" is.

Comment: Perhaps we're using different terminology, but I would disagree that `2 8 320` is a subsequence of `9 2 3 7 8 14 39 145 76 320`.

Comment: @JohnGordon 2 divides 8 ,8 divides 320 so 2,8,320

Comment: @UjjwalPawar: a *subsequence* is a sequence of *consecutive* numbers. So `9, 2, 37` is a subsequence, but `2, 8, 320` is not because they are not adjacent.

Comment: I have edited the question with the terminology he is using.. It can be found here: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/DIVSEQ

Comment: read more here http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/oct2004/Advanced-1.php

Comment: Ah, turns out that [in mathematics a subsequence is any ordered sequence where some elements were dropped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence), so the terminology is correct here.

Comment: It sems that you're looking for directed graph diameter: numbers are *vertixes*, divides are edges (so `2` connected to `8`, `14`, `76` and `320`)

Comment: Your `i` and `j` aren't quite the same as their `i` and `j`.

Comment: @user2357112 am I missing something? Yes it is.

Comment: I agree with Dmitry that graph theory is the way to go on this one. Iterate through each node and point it forward to everything it divides that's of a higher index, then traverse the tree depth-first from the beginning to find the longest branch.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Which is greater, `i` or `j`?

Comment: @user2357112 ah ha, you're right. Good call

Answer (score 4):

As `j < i`, you need to check whether `a[j]` is a divider of `a[i]`, not vice versa. So this means you need to put this condition (and *only* this one, not combined with the inverse):

```
        if (ar[i]%ar[j]==0):
```

With this change the output for the given sample data is 3.

The confusion comes from the definition, in which `i < j`, while in your code `j < i`.

Answer (score 3):

This solves your problem without using any recursion :)

```
n = int(input())
ar = []
bestvals = []
best_stored = []
for x in range(n):
  ar.append(int(input()))
  best_stored.append(0)

best_stored[0] = 1

for i in range(n):
  maxval = 1
  for j in range(i):
    if ar[i] % ar[j] == 0:
      maxval = max(maxval,(best_stored[j])+1)
  best_stored[i] = maxval

print(max(best_stored))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the graph theory solution I alluded to in a comment:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child_x):
        # Not actually used here, but a useful alternate constructor!
        new = self.__class__(child_x)
        self.children.append(new)
        return new

    def how_deep(self):
        """Does a DFS to return how deep the deepest branch goes."""

        maxdepth = 1
        for child in self.children:
            maxdepth = max(maxdepth, child.how_deep()+1)
        return maxdepth

nums = [9, 2, 3, 7, 8, 14, 39, 145, 76, 320]
nodes = [Node(num) for num in nums]
for i,node in enumerate(nodes):
    for other in nodes[i:]:
        if other.x % node.x == 0:
            node.children.append(other)
# graph built, rooted at nodes[0]

result = max([n.how_deep() for n in nodes])
```